# Considering upgrading to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm thinking of upgrading a current Rails 2.3.8 / Ruby 1.8.6 app to Rails 3 / Ruby 1.8.7. Seeing that Rails 3 has been out for a month now, are there big issues that developers have ran into upgrading 2.x app besides the expected some gems aren't supported yet, deprecation warnings / methods, etc? Are there major stability issues with Rails 3? Usually when a new major release comes out, it takes several months to work through initial kinks so I'm hoping to time it appropriately.

Thanks in advance for your feedback and insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a fairly complicated app that I've made two (aborted) attempts to port. There are several parts of your app that will need to be changed, although the real problem for me was gem compatibility.

Short answer - if you're using a lot of third party gems, then you should wait. If you're app is relatively pure, then its probably worth upgrading now.

Edit: one more thing to add. make sure you have a robust set of tests before you start porting. That will tell you instantly what's working and what's not, and give you confidence in your port.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Another issue with gems is there there is no one place I can go to verify compatibility, it's a painfully manual process.

Comment: Unfortunately not that I know of... :(

Comment: Here's a place to verify plugin/gem compatibility with Rails 3: http://www.railsplugins.org/